# What are the benefits of interlocking the fingers on club grip?

Tags: technique, golf

When holding my clubs, I have always adopted a "baseball bat" style grip.  I've played like this for a few years and haven't had any noticeable issues.

However, a lot of players, both pro and amateur, use a grip with two interlocking fingers.

What are the benefits of this grip?  Is it worth changing or is it personal preference?

Comment: I myself use the baseball grip and I have recently considered changing and I ended after lots of research changing to an interlocking, since then in the last year I have dropped from 8- 1 and I am still improving, the baseball grip isn't the way to go. It causes other issues like a strong hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How tight you hold the club may be just as or even more important than what style of grip you use. From what I can tell choosing a grip appears to be a **personal preference**. I wouldn't switch from the grip you are currently using unless you **really** feel you need a change. :–)

However, it should be noted that there are always people who have strong opinions on what is best. [**Perfect Golf Swing Review**](http://perfectgolfswingreview.net/grip.htm) states that the use of either the Interlocking grip or Vardon Overlap grip is very important. Saying that the "**Baseball grip promotes a flipping *of the wrist(s)* in the late downswing, which is a major swing fault**".

The following article from *golf.about.com* does a very good job describing the three primary grips. Your grip is on the list (Baseball Grip).

> [Holding the Handle - The Three Primary Grips](http://golf.about.com/od/golftips/ss/griptypes.htm)
>
> The Vardon Overlap, sometimes called the [Overlapping Grip](http://golf.about.com/od/golftips/ss/griptypes_2.htm), is the
>   most common grip among great players. *Not one of the two mentioned by
>   your question*
>
> …
>
> The next most common grip is called the Interlock, or
>   [Interlocking](http://golf.about.com/od/golftips/ss/griptypes_3.htm). This grip is very popular on the LPGA Tour and has
>   been used by many top male players including Jack Nicklaus and Tiger
>   Woods. This grip literally locks the hands together, but the golfer
>   also runs the risk of having the handle stray into the palms of the
>   hands. People with small hands, weak forearms and wrists, and
>   beginners in many cases prefer this style of grip.
>
> …
>
> The Ten Finger grip (sometimes called the [Baseball Grip](http://golf.about.com/od/golftips/ss/griptypes_4.htm)) is the
>   **least preferred grip** among teachers. It does, however, have its
>   advantages.
>
> …
>
> People who experience joint pain, have arthritis or small, weak hands
>   often benefit by using the Ten Finger grip.
>
> …
>
> ```
> Holding the Handle - The Three Primary Grips (golf.about.com)
> From Michael Lamanna, Director of Instruction, The Phoenician
> ```

Comment: Thank you.  I might give the Vardon Overlap a try.  The interlocking just feels way too alien to me.

Comment: The Vardon is pretty much a hybrid of baseball (ten-finger) and interlocking; it has the advantage over interlocking of keeping your entire lead hand firmly on the grip to prevent helicoptering, without having the entire trailing hand on the grip like baseball which can open the clubface causing slices.

Comment: I also use the baseball grip, as it feels most natural. I'll echo that if you're doing well with a baseball, stick with it. Most coaches will only change your grip if they feel it'll correct some other problems with your mechanics, particularly any tendency to open the club.

Answer (score 3):

I am a teenager and have been playing golf for 3 years now and maintain a handicap of 2. I used an overlapping grip up until 4 months ago where I switched to an interlocking grip to keep my hands closer to together and level out my shoulders. It did feel very strange at first but now I can't imagine using the old grip. My posture at address is now much better and can maintain a better swing with less compensation and hit draws better than ever (as they require a better technique, for the body to leave room for the arms, as apposed to a fayde which comes from the outside and stays in front of the body).

So the benefits of an interlocking grip are keeping your hands closer together, levelling out your shoulders and the ability to hold onto the club securely but softly.